# How to convert JObject into JArray in f#

Tags: f#

I want to convert this **tablesinJson**  into **JArray** and loop through it.

`let tablesInJson = (JArray)jsonModel["tables"];`

Something simmilar as we do in C#

```
 let json = "{
    "table": [{
        "boolean": true,
        "null": null,
        "number": 123,
        "string": "Hello World"
    }]
}"

    let ConvertFoo (jsonModel : JObject) (TableInfo : TableInfo list) =
        let tablesinJson = jsonModel.["tables"]

        //convert tablesinJson into JArray and loop through it
        //let tablesInJson = (JArray)jsonModel["tables"]; something like this

        printfn "%O" jsonModel.["tables"]
        printfn "%O" sqlTableInfos


    let _json= JObject.Parse(json)
    let list = [TableName "one" ; ColumnName "table"]
    ConvertFoo _json list
```

Comment: Are you looking for the f# downcast operator: `let tablesInJson = jsonModel.["table"] :?> JArray`, or is there something else that you are having trouble with?

Comment: Yeah exactly and after that, I want to loop through that JArray @Mankarse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A minimal example that iterates over all the objects in the `table` field and prints the `string` field is:

```
open Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

let parsed = JObject.Parse(json)
let tables = parsed.["table"] :?> JArray
for table in tables do 
  let value = table.["string"] :?> JValue
  printfn "%O" value
```

As mentioned in the comments, you need to use the `:?>` operator to cast the object to `JArray` (so that you can iterate over it using `for`) or to `JValue` (so that you can access the value).

It might be worth noting that you could do the same thing using the [Json type provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/) from F# Data and you would avoid all the casting because the type provider infers the types and exposes all nested data as members:

```
open FSharp.Data

[<Literal>]
let json = """{ "table": [ {"boolean": true, "null": null,
  "number": 123,"string": "Hello World" }]}"""
type Parser = JsonProvider<json>

let parsed = Parser.Load(json)
for table in parsed.Table do
  printfn "%s" table.String
```